# How to copy all information from image to another image using pillow python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How can I copy all information from image1 to image2. Image1 contains GPS information and other information. the question is how take all these information from image1 and put into image2.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

img1=Image.open('image1_path')
img2=Image.new(mode=img1.mode,size=img1.size)
img2.paste(img1)
```